# How to quickly find the basis of Null space in GF2

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix $A$ contains only 1 and 0. The operations is defined as in GF2, e.g., 1+0=1, 1+1=0, 0+0=0.

I know how to make $A$ into row echelon form. For example, my $A$ now becomes

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Is there a way that we can directly read the basis of Null space from this row echelon form?

Comment: I suggest first putting A in reduced row echelon form and updating your question with that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to put $A$ into rref.  In particular, we have

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ===> 

1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ===>

1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ===> 

1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ===> 

1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Now, the pivot rows of the free columns will form entries of the basis, with one basis element per free column.  Each basis element is found by setting a free variable (in this case, $x_6,\dots,x_9$) equal to $1$ and all others equal to $0$.